# I get the Malformed access token for Facebook in ios 6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I want to fetch the facebook friends profile picture.I also give the access_token for it.

I search a lot on net but didn't got any good solution.

my code is as follow:

```
- (IBAction)advancedButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
    ACAccountType *FBaccountType= [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    //NSString *key = @"xxxxxx";

    NSString *key = @"xxxxxx";
    NSDictionary *dictFB = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:key,ACFacebookAppIdKey,@[@"email"],ACFacebookPermissionsKey, nil];


        [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:dictFB completion:
         ^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {
             if (granted) {
                 NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:FBaccountType];
                 //it will always be the last object with single sign on
                 self.facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
                    NSLog(@"facebook account =%@",self.facebookAccount);

                 ACAccountCredential *fbCredential = [self.facebookAccount credential];
                accessToken = [fbCredential oauthToken];
                 NSLog(@"Facebook Access Token: %@", accessToken);

                 [self get];
             } else {
                 //Fail gracefully...
              NSLog(@"error getting permission %@",e);

             }
         }];

}


-(void)fr
{
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id,name,picture,first_name,last_name,gender&access_token=BAAFcRQZCZAUeUBAICacM2q1V5UzRHee6xHGnbEdu19v6CZBIEDJmTwHBKtMZBwtVuFiEeuXqt4yKeSkeI17QZBGaZCeszBfOKdbZAfR4E9RN2nFqHalKPXZBga96WQCU8CSNG4ZCJCK1V7JIbqZAPRgNl6mjjO4Ns1CEaLpbXUYtum1CXbNqTtT82YpVVKoZCmMEBpqHfwYMx1OKu9RZBsjPZA6DlhKA1uGyU32EGJ8QOQZASJVQZDZD"];

    SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                            requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                      URL:requestURL
                                               parameters:nil];
    request.account = self.facebookAccount;



    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                         NSHTTPURLResponse *response,
                                         NSError *error) {

        if(!error)
        {
            list =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

            NSLog(@"Dictionary contains data: %@", list );
            if([list objectForKey:@"error"]!=nil)
            {
                [self attemptRenewCredentials];
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                nameLabel.text = [list objectForKey:@"username"];
            });
        }
        else{
            //handle error gracefully
            NSLog(@"error from get%@",error);
            //attempt to revalidate credentials
        }

    }];
}
```

**But i always got the error like this:**

```
error =     {
        code = 190;
        message = "Malformed access token BAAFcRQZCZAUeUBAICacM2q1V5UzRHee6xHGnbEdu19v6CZBIEDJmTwHBKtMZBwtVuFiEeuXqt4yKeSkeI17QZBGaZCeszBfOKdbZAfR4E9RN2nFqHalKPXZBga96WQCU8CSNG4ZCJCK1V7JIbqZAPRgNl6mjjO4Ns1CEaLpbXUYtum1CXbNqTtT82YpVVKoZCmMEBpqHfwYMx1OKu9RZBsjPZA6DlhKA1uGyU32EGJ8QOQZASJVQZDZD?access_token=BAAFcRQZCZAUeUBAHBZBSdTL9wWFDOVthxj78bBJlrNEkPiKHdxZA1HaRmO9dtBTJdsZCtZCu2vaE5ByZAdK7Ox30BpIR0KTg0ZC6pi1IOE0KnZCZBSxqbycG0C6Ws5Ct4ferL3G0VU1wIfDypKekFM3zB4r5gAiUREQ66Yuz2Fu2mp5NGqZCBE1p357H41P2lKOAQN9EZAmu4q3SRtjMuVIw4dtdC00l4RhMuDWTOIUQlO54bgZDZD";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
}
```

**I can't able to solve this. Help me!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an SLRequest, it will auto append the access token for you, and you also should not have any request params in the URL itself. Instead, you should do something like:

```
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends"];

SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                        requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                  URL:requestURL
                                           parameters:@{@"fields":@"id,name,picture,first_name,last_name,gender"}];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  yes, that is working! But how can i fetch the friend list who use the app?

Comment: add "installed" to your list of fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this instead of using SLRequest.It is also

```
             NSURL *meurl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=%@",fbAccessToken]];

             NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:meurl];

             [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

                   NSString *userDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

             }];
```